Angular - DxDataGridComponent doesn't wait for data download to end before exporting grid to excel file
I have a grid that exports too soon, specifically before all data have finished downloading. Moreover, if I press the export button a second time, the export is correct, since after the first time, all data has been set correctly. How can I fix this and make it so that when I press export, the grid gets exported only when all data has finished downloading?
This is the html main page file:
<div class="page">
      <div class="actions">
       <custom-button
        class="mr-1"
        (click)="exportAll = true; searchPage?.grid?.exportGrid()"
        title="Download excel file">
        <i class="fad fa-file-excel"></i>
       </custom-button>
      </div>

   <div class="page-content">
        <search-page
          #searchPage
          [packages]="dataSource$ | dataSource"
          [orders]="
            packagesList.selectOrders$ | ngrxPush
          "
          [users]="packagesList.selectUsers$ | ngrxPush"
          [warehouses]="packagesList.selectWarehouses$ | ngrxPush"
          [loaded]="packagesList.selectIsInitialized$ | ngrxPush"
          [error]="packagesList.selectIsErrored$ | ngrxPush"
           ></search-page>
       </div>
    </div>

This is the main page ts file:
    @Component({
      selector: 'main-page',
      templateUrl: './main-page.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./main-page.component.scss'],
      providers: [
        provideComponentStore(PackagesListUseCase),
      ],
 })

export class PackagesPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
          @ViewChild('searchPage', { static: false })
      searchPage? : PackagesSearchComponent

          constructor(
            public packagesList: PackagesListUseCase,
          ) {}
    
    
      dataSource$ = (loadOptions: LoadOptions): Observable<Page<Package>> => {
        const params = parseLoadOptions<
          PackageSearchParams,
          PackageSearchField,
          PackageSortField
        >(loadOptions, packagesFilterParams, packagesSortParams)

    this.exportAll
      ? this.packagesList.searchAll$(params)
      : this.packagesList.search$(params)
    return this.packagesList.selectPage$.pipe(
      take(1),
      finalize(() => {
        this.exportAll = false
      }),
    )
  }
//Rest of the code

Then there's the use case file:
interface PackagesListState {
  data?: Packages[]
  extData?: PackagesListingData
  totalCount?: number
  fields?: PackageSearchField[]
  filters?: PackageSearchParams
  error?: HttpErrorResponse
  toReload: boolean
  isLoading: boolean
  isInitialized: boolean
}

const INITIAL_STATE: PackagesListState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isInitialized: false,
  toReload: false,
}

@Injectable()
export class PackagesListUseCase extends ComponentStore<PackagesListState> {
  constructor(private packagesRepository: PackagesRepository) {
    super(INITIAL_STATE)
  }

  readonly selectIsLoading$: Observable<boolean> = this.select(
    (state) => state.isLoading,
  )


  readonly selectPackages$: Observable<Package[]> = this.select(
    (state) => state.data || [],
  )

 readonly selectTotalCount$: Observable<number> = this.select(
    (state) => state.totalCount || 0,
  )

  readonly selectPage$: Observable<Page<Package>> =
    this.selectIsLoading$.pipe(
      filter((isLoading) => !isLoading),
      switchMap(() =>
        this.select(
          this.selectPackages$,
          this.selectTotalCount$,
          (data, totalCount) => ({ totalCount, data }),
          { debounce: true },
        ),
      ),
    )

  readonly search$ = this.effect(
    (searchParams$: Observable<PackageSearchParams>) => {
      return searchParams$.pipe(
        tap((searchParams) => this.setFilters(searchParams)),
        withLatestFrom(this.selectState$),
        filter(([_, state]) => !!state.fields),
        switchMap(([_, state]) =>
          this.packagesRepository
            .searchPackages$(
              this.parseStateFilterParams(state),
              state.fields || [],
              state.extData,
            )
            .pipe(
              tapResponse(
                (pageData) => {
                  this.setPage(pageData)
                },
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.setError(error),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      )
    },
  )

  readonly searchAll$ = this.effect(
    (searchParams$: Observable<PackageSearchParams>) => {
      return searchParams$.pipe(
        tap((searchParams) => this.setFilters(searchParams)),
        withLatestFrom(this.selectState$),
        map(([params, state]) => ({
          params: { ...params, limit: state.totalCount },
          fields: state.fields,
          extData: state.extData,
        })),
        switchMap(({ params, fields, extData }) =>
          this.packagesRepository
            .searchPackages$(params, fields ?? [], extData)
            .pipe(
              tapResponse(
                (pageData) => this.setPage(pageData),
                (error: HttpErrorResponse) => this.setError(error),
              ),
            ),
        ),
      )
    },
  )

  readonly setPage = this.updater(
    (state, page: PackagesListState): PackagesListState => {
      return {
        ...state,
        data: page.data,
        extData: page.extData,
        totalCount: page.totalCount,
        toReload: false,
        isLoading: false,
        isInitialized: true,
      }
    },
  )
//Rest of the code

Lastly, the search page:
@Component({
  selector: 'search-page',
  templateUrl: './search-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-page.component.scss'],
})
export class PackagesSearchComponent {
  @ViewChild('grid', { static: false }) grid?: DxDataGridComponent
  @Input() packages?: DataSource
  @Input() warehouses?: Warehouse[]
  @Input() orders?: Orders[]
  @Input() users?: User[]
  @Input() filtered? = false
  @Input() editable? = false
  @Input() loaded? = false
  @Input() error? = false
  @Input() fileName = 'packages'

  exportGrid(extData?: PackingListsListingData) {
    this.orders = extData?.orders
    this.users = extData?.users
    this.warehouses = extData?.warehouses
    if (this.grid) {
      exportGrid(
        this.grid.instance,
        this.fileName,
        this.fileName,
        this.customizeExcelCell,
      )
    }
  }
//Rest of the code

And the export function:
export function exportGrid(
  component: dxDataGrid,
  fileName: string,
  sheetName = 'Sheet',
  customizeCell?: (options: {
    gridCell?: DataGridCell
    excelCell?: any
  }) => void,
  catalog?: string,
): void {
  const workbook = new Workbook()
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet(sheetName)
  exportDataGrid({
    component: component,
    worksheet: worksheet,
    selectedRowsOnly: false,
    autoFilterEnabled: true,
    loadPanel: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    customizeCell,
  }).then(() =>
    workbook.xlsx
      .writeBuffer()
      .then((buffer: BlobPart) =>
        saveAs(
          new Blob([buffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' }),
          `${fileName}.xlsx`,
        ),
      ),
  )
}

As I said above, I believe it's a state/data loading problem, since by pressing one time the export button, the grid gets exported partially, while when pressing it a second time it gets exported fully (specifically, since the grid has pagination, it exports the whole list of packages but with only the external data, that is to say orders users and warehouses, related to the first 15 packages, which is the default pagination setting).
I tried adding booleans to wait for the export of the grid, but if I don't call grid?.exportGrid() the dataSource$ doesn't get reloaded... How can I fix this?
